# Onscreen keyboard in chrome on a touchscreen laptop running with Gnome?

Tags: gnome, touch-screen

I recently got a Lenovo Yoga 2 13 inch. It came with windows 8.1 which works great. I decided to install Linux(Fedora 25) and so far(with the exception of wi-fi) works great. However, when trying to use the tablet mode, which disables the keyboard, I can't get the onscreen keyboard to show up in Chrome(running newest chrome 55). Does anyone know any way to "force" the keyboard to show in chrome?

The problem happens in both `Wayland` and `Xorg` sessions.

Comment: The Chrome Web Store has a selection of virtual onscreen keyboards you can install for use within the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of experimenting I found out that there is already a gesture in GNOME(or maybe in a more recent version) that lets me start the onscreen keyboard. I simply had to swipe with one finger bottom-up from the bottom edge of the screen. This works for all apps, not just chrome.

Comment: Does this work for Wayland too?

Comment: @JohnDoe yes, it works at least for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Install Florence Virtual Keyboard on Linux](http://xmodulo.com/onscreen-virtual-keyboard-linux.html) This will help you to get the on screen keyboard.